# SQL Server: join on derived table that contains WITH clause?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, row-number, derived-table

I'd like to join on a subquery / derived table that contains a WITH clause (the WITH clause is necessary to filter on `ROW_NUMBER() = 1`).  In Teradata something similar would work fine, but Teradata uses `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() = 1` instead of a WITH clause.

Here is my attempt at this join:

```
-- want to join row with max StartDate on JobModelID
INNER JOIN (
    WITH AllRuns AS (
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobModelID ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM Runs
    )
    SELECT * FROM AllRuns WHERE RowNumber = 1
) Runs
ON JobModels.JobModelID = Runs.JobModelID
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a join condition is probably less efficient, but usually works fine for me.

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (PARTITION BY JobModelID 
           ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS RowNumber
      FROM Runs
    ) Runs
ON JobModels.JobModelID = Runs.JobModelID 
AND Runs.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Any idea how much less efficient this would be?

Comment: @jnylen, Have you made any attempt to profile this query? Execution plans, Profiler, Client Statistics?

Comment: @jnylen:  I agree with astander.  My rule of thumb:  if the query comes back in a reasonable amount of time, it's ok.  If not, I start looking for hotspots and try to refactor.  I've never had to refactor code like what I've shown above.

Comment: I don't have enough data where it would matter yet (still in development phase).  The amount of data will probably stay pretty small anyway, so I was just looking for something subjective.

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple WITH clauses. Something like

```
;WITH AllRuns AS ( 
        SELECT  *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobModelID ORDER BY StartDate DESC) AS RowNumber 
        FROM    Runs 
),
Runs AS(
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    AllRuns 
        WHERE   RowNumber = 1
)

SELECT  *
FROM    ... INNER JOIN ( 
        Runs ON JobModels.JobModelID = Runs.JobModelID
```

For more detail on the usages/structure/rules see [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: Ugly, but it seems to work.  What's the fundamental issue here - lack of support for WITH clauses in derived tables?  Also, I was able to eliminate the second WITH clause by joining on `(SELECT * FROM AllRuns WHERE RowNumber = 1)`.

Comment: I would disaggree on the fact that multiple sattements in a with clause is UGLY. It is slightly different sintac to multiple layered sub selects, **which in most cases makes it extremely hard to read.**

Comment: I mean ugly in the sense that the SQL for doing the subquery's task (filtering the `Runs` table to get one row per `JobModelID`) is now split between the beginning of the query and the subquery.